# How to logout using the API?

Tags: support, api, logout

I  have recently developed my own Stack Overflow Android App, by using [Stack Exchange  API](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs).

I am logging into Stack Overflow by using [Authentication OAuth 2.0 implicit](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/authentication) with Google. I got `access_token` and Api key from StackApps, and I can successfully read all the data. It's fine now, but I want to implement logout functionality.

How to logout from `Google` here using the API? Do I need to invalidate my `access_token` in this situation?

Please give me some hint how to do this?

Comment: Duplicate of those two: http://stackapps.com/questions/2831/how-to-provide-a-logout-button-for-authentication, http://stackapps.com/questions/3611/logging-out-so-another-user-can-log-in (in short: not possible)

Comment: @ShadowWizard God damn!! It's not possible then why should they provide this `API` ?

Comment: Don't ask me... Kevin (who answered both questions) is SE developer working on the API, you can ask him (politely please) in a comment.

Comment: @MD that 'God damn' comment was priceless. hahahaha. I think it's a normal reaction xD

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did after 4 hours.

It's not official way but right now i have no other way (Patch). I just clear all **Cookies**.

```
public void clearCookies(){
    CookieSyncManager.createInstance(WebViewActivity.this);
    CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
    cookieManager.removeAllCookie();
}
```

Comment: Well, it's not really related to the API then, but if it works. it works. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard May be you're right but still i can't find a way to `logout`. but it worked right now.it worked.

Answer (score 5):

A better way is to invalidate the token

```
/access-tokens/{accessTokens}/invalidate
```